# Проброс портов на raspberry pi

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables, raspberry-pi

Есть Raspberry Pi с интерфейсами wlan0 и eth0.

Eth0 присвоен статический ip 192.168.0.2
На интерфейс eth0 подключена ip-камера с ip 192.168.0.110

raspberry pi подключается к интернету через wlan0 (по wi-fi модему со статическим ip) модемом ей так же присвоен статический Ip 192.167.0.2

Необходимо сделать ip-камеру доступной из сети по порту 81.

пробовал следующую команду

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 81 -i wlan0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.110:81
```

ничего не вышло. с iptables дружу очень плохо. Помогите решить данную проблему

Comment: Здесь всё правильно. Значит, проблема не в iptables, а где-то в другом месте — роутинг, скорее всего. Может, невключенный форвардинг пакетов. Смотрите tcpdump-ом c Pi.

Comment: BTW, имейте в виду, что сеть 192.167 — это не серые адреса, вообще-то.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev это рукожопство) серые - значит за натом. там он мог и 8.168.0.0/24 сделать) что только не видел в локальных сетях...

Answer (score 3):

Во первых включить форвард

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"| sudo tee  /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf
```

Во вторых `192.167.0.0/24` это моветон